# Output of difftime in other unit

Tags: r, date-formatting

I created some vector of dates with hours and sorted it:

```
h <- c(16, 12, 21, 8)
m <- c(42, 24, 58, 19)
s <- c(1, 15, 56, 45)

   hours <- mapply(function(i){
      time <- paste(h[i], m[i], s[i], sep=":")
      time <- strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S")
      time <- strftime(time)
   }, 1:length(h))
   asc <- sort(hours)
   asc <- as.POSIXct(asc, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Now I want to count the difference between events but the result should be in second (actually, only hours, minutes ans second matter). When I use `difftime` I get result like this:

`> asc[1]-asc[2]`

`Time difference of -4.075 hours`

But I want the result to be in second and exact. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `difftime` explicitly where you can specify the units:

```
difftime(asc[1],asc[2],units="secs")
Time difference of -14670 secs
```